# Who are they and what do they believe in?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

English is not my native language so forgive me if my poem  ̶s̶u̶c̶k̶s̶ isn't very well written. It might not even be a *poem* at all. The riddle still counts, though:

> *Some people come to me all the time
>
>   If they express themselves well enough
>
>   They might get what they're looking for*
>
> *I fight against experts
>
>   I should be sending them gifts
>
>   And flowers
>
>   And thank-you letters*
>
> *Every now and then I have some insights
>
>   Not all of them see the light
>
>   I remember having one in a leap year
>
>   It was bigger than the last of it's kind
>
>   These people believe in strange things, right?*

Question:

#### Who are these people and what is the strange thing they believe in?

---

**HINT 1**

> I'll always strive to be welcoming, even if you don't express yourself well. But that might not always be the case. You might have the door slammed in your face.

**HINT 2**

> Who's Your Arch-Enemy?

**HINT 3**

> I'm an *exception*.

**HINT 4**

> Most of these people prefer dogs over cats.

**HINT 5**

> CH 22-03-09

Comment: A quick note - it appears that you have not accepted an answer on any of your questions. It might be a good idea to address a few of those (add hints, add a bounty, accept an existing answer) before posting more questions. Part of PSE's goal is to stand as a depository of excellent puzzles. Multiple unanswered puzzles can detract from that goal. Have a great day, and Happy Puzzling!

Comment: @Brandon_J He's only posted 4 questions so far (including this one), all in the last week or so, and he's been actively adding hints.

Comment: @Randal'Thor for sure - I should have made clearer that there is (currently) no problem whatsoever. I was trying to avert a future problem that could arise if he doesn't accept answers/tend to old questions in the long-term. But yes, to repeat: **There is currently no problem**.

Comment: You say "some people come to me", then say "I fight against experts", then ask "Who are these people?". Are you asking who the people who come to you are? Who you are?

Comment: @Acccumulation _These people believe in strange things, right?_ -> When you find out what the _insights_ are, then you'll know who "these people" are.

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER:**
Political content and conspiracy theory follow. This answer is unlikely to be accepted since the OP has gone dark. Nevertheless, I post for reasons that will be explained at the end of the post.

**ANSWER:**
These people are

> the citizens of the People's Republic of China and they believe the policies and propaganda of the Communist Party of China.

**REASONING:**
Some people come to me all the time
If they express themselves well enough
They might get what they're looking for

> People, or rather businesses, set up shop in China all the time and if they do not anger the Party they just might get the profit they are looking for.

I fight against experts
I should be sending them gifts
And flowers
And thank-you letters

> The experts are the US-Europe with which China is locked in ideological conflict. However, the hegemon of the East should be "thankful" to its rivals West for providing investment and markets that paved the way for its rise.

Every now and then I have some insights
Not all of them see the light
I remember having one in a leap year
It was bigger than the last of it's kind
These people believe in strange things, right?

> [Xi Jinping Thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_Jinping_Thought#History), now an official doctrine of the Party, was gradually developed from 2012 (a leap year). It was affirmed by the Party in 2017 making Xi join the ranks of titans Mao and Deng.

**HINTS:**

> 1. China is welcoming of some ideas (intellectual property) and  hostile to others (liberal, democratic ideals).
>  2. Being used primarily by English speakers, the natural Arch-Enemy of the reader is China.
>  3. [Chinese exceptionalism](https://www.economist.com/open-future/2018/06/13/chinas-exceptionalism-rewrites-the-western-political-playbook) is a branch of Chinese political theory.
>  4. Might be a reference to the Chinese social norm of having dogs as part of the diet.
>  5. CH 22-03-09 could be a reference to the 93 Tibetan monks attacking a Chinese police station in March 22, 2009.

---

结束。习主席万岁。

Are they gone? Okay, I think the CPC agents are no longer here.
If you are willing to know the truth, do so knowing that I cannot guarantee you or your loved ones' safety.

You have been warned.

**TIN-FOIL HAT ALERT:**

> The OP is a citizen of the PRC and is critical of the government. He found a way through the Great Firewall to post this riddle as his personal protest and let the world know that voices yearning for freedom lie beyond the bamboo curtain. Despite his best efforts though, he was soon found out by Chinese thought-crime police. His account in PSE has since been disabled and his current whereabouts unknown.
>
> However, the flame of user60411's dissent shall not vanish along with him. I post this answer in solidarity with user60411 and all the userXXXX's of the world who believe that Stack Exchange content should be regulated by community moderators and not government censors.
>
> We will never forget.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt that may lead to a full answer:

I believe you may be:

> Anti-vaxxers

Some people come to me all the time
If they express themselves well enough
They might get what they're looking for

> Sounds like this is coming from Google (people come to search for answers and need to express themselves correctly to get them)

I fight against experts
I should be sending them gifts
And flowers
And thank-you letters

> While experts often produce scientific answers, Google and other online sources can provide answers that are, let's say, less scientific

Every now and then I have some insights
Not all of them see the light

> Many results from a Google search, but only the first few are generally looked at

I remember having one in a leap year
It was bigger than the last of it's kind

> I was really hoping the last Measles outbreak (1994) was a leap year, but it was not.  Stumped.

These people believe in strange things, right?

> This would fit with some people's view of anti-vax believers

Comment: That one's far from the target. Things appear to fit in the first part but after that you start slipping. For example, 3rd spoiler doesn't explain the *"I should be sending them gifts And flowers And thank-you letters"* part.